# Is there a way to run a function on mouse hovering until a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function increase (element) {
    count = Number(element.innerText)
    count += 1
    element.innerText = count
}
function decrease (element) {
    count = Number(element.innerText)
    count -= 1
    element.innerText = count
}
```

```
    <div class="textbox textbox-1" id="textboxjs1" onmouseover="decrease(textboxEl2),decrease(textboxEl3),decrease(textboxEl4),decrease(textboxEl5),decrease(textboxEl6)"> < Prev </div>
    <div class="textbox textbox-2" id="textboxjs2" onclick="increase(textboxEl2)"> 1 </div>
    <div class="textbox textbox-3" id="textboxjs3" onclick="increase(textboxEl3)"> 2 </div>
    <div class="textbox textbox-4" id="textboxjs4" onclick="increase(textboxEl4)"> 3 </div>
    <div class="textbox textbox-5" id="textboxjs5" onclick="increase(textboxEl5)"> 4 </div>
    <div class="textbox textbox-6" id="textboxjs6" onclick="increase(textboxEl6)"> 5 </div>
    <div class="textbox textbox-7" id="textboxjs7" onmouseover="increase(textboxEl2), increase(textboxEl3), increase(textboxEl4), increase(textboxEl5), increase(textboxEl6)"> Next > </div>
```

Hello, is there any way I can make the numbers go up WHILE I keep my mouse hovering on the " Next " button? This is the code I came up with but it only increases once, when my mouse enters the area, I want to make it continuously increase until I take my mouse out, how can I do that?
Hopefully this isn't too messy, I'm only 2 days into programming :)

Comment: Try onmousemove, onmouseenter and onmouseleave. You may need to resort to `.addEventListener('mousemove', increase)` etc. if the event proprty doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` event handlers and `setInterval` and `clearInterval` timer functions.

```js
const textboxEl2 = document.getElementById('textboxjs2');
const textboxEl3 = document.getElementById('textboxjs3');
const textboxEl4 = document.getElementById('textboxjs4');
const textboxEl5 = document.getElementById('textboxjs5');
const textboxEl6 = document.getElementById('textboxjs6');
let decrementTimer = null;
let incrementTimer = null;

function increase(element) {
    count = Number(element.innerText)
    count += 1
    element.innerText = count
}

function decrease(element) {
    count = Number(element.innerText)
    count -= 1
    element.innerText = count
}

function decreaseAll() {
    decrease(textboxEl2);
    decrease(textboxEl3);
    decrease(textboxEl4);
    decrease(textboxEl5);
    decrease(textboxEl6);
}

function increaseAll() {
    increase(textboxEl2);
    increase(textboxEl3);
    increase(textboxEl4);
    increase(textboxEl5);
    increase(textboxEl6);
}

function decrementMouseEnterHandler() {
    decrementTimer = setInterval(function aMomentLater() {
        decreaseAll();
    }, 100);
}

function decrementMouseLeaveHandler() {
    clearInterval(decrementTimer);
}

function incrementMouseEnterHandler() {
    incrementTimer = setInterval(function aMomentLater() {
        increaseAll();
    }, 100);
}

function incrementMouseLeaveHandler() {
    clearInterval(incrementTimer);
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox textbox-1" id="textboxjs1" 
  onmouseenter="decrementMouseEnterHandler()"
  onmouseleave="decrementMouseLeaveHandler()"
  >&#60; Prev</div>

<div class="textbox textbox-2" id="textboxjs2" onclick="increase(textboxEl2)"> 1 </div>
<div class="textbox textbox-3" id="textboxjs3" onclick="increase(textboxEl3)"> 2 </div>
<div class="textbox textbox-4" id="textboxjs4" onclick="increase(textboxEl4)"> 3 </div>
<div class="textbox textbox-5" id="textboxjs5" onclick="increase(textboxEl5)"> 4 </div>
<div class="textbox textbox-6" id="textboxjs6" onclick="increase(textboxEl6)"> 5 </div>

<div class="textbox textbox-7" id="textboxjs7" 
    onmouseenter="incrementMouseEnterHandler()"
    onmouseleave="incrementMouseLeaveHandler()"
  >Next &#62;</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gk9Ly42z/3/).

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo example showing how to implement the logic to start/stop incrementing/decrementing the number contained in a dom element.

Each div has two event handlers: `mouseover` and `mouseout`

When the mouse is over a `.target` element, it starts incrementing  its content at a given time interval (defined by `speed`) and the timer gets stored in a specific data attribute of the element itself.

When the mouse is out of a `.target` element, its timer gets retrieved from its data attributes, and cleared so that it won't run anymore at the next iteration.

When the div with `.next` and `.prev` class is the element to be hovered, the increment/decrement feature will target all the `.target` divs instead of one only.

This version is slightly more complicated that what I showed before but it covers the whole story, including decrementing, and decouples the timer function from how to grab the context.

From MDN:

- [mouseout event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event)
- [mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)
- [timeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval)

```js
//milliseconds between each timer steps
const speed = 100;

//adds event handlers for all divs matching .target, .next and .prev
const targetDivs =
  document.querySelectorAll('.target, .next, .prev');
for(let e of targetDivs){
  e.addEventListener('mouseover', startTimer);
  e.addEventListener('mouseout', stopTimer);
}

//increases the number contained inside the elements passed
function increase(elements) {
  for(let element of elements){
    let count = parseInt(element.innerText);
    element.innerText = ++count;
  }
}

//decreases the number contained inside the elements passed
function decrease(elements) {
  for(let element of elements){
    let count = parseInt(element.innerText);
    element.innerText = --count;
  }
}

function startTimer(){
  let c = grabContext(this);
  let t = setInterval( () => c.functionToCall(c.targets), speed );
  this.setAttribute('data-timer', t);
}

function stopTimer(){
  let t = this.getAttribute('data-timer');
  clearInterval(t);
}

//Grab the context for a given element (it's a next/prev/target?)
function grabContext(element){
  
  //classList of this element
  let classList = element.classList;
  //elements to be targeted
  let targets = [];
  //function to be called bound to this element
  let functionToCall;
  
  //if the element contains .next in its class
  if( classList.contains('next') ){
    targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
    functionToCall = increase;
  }
  //if the element contains .prev in its class
  else if( classList.contains('prev') ){
    targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
    functionToCall = decrease;
  }
  //else
  else{
    targets = [element];
    functionToCall = increase;
  }
  
  return {
    targets: targets,
    functionToCall: functionToCall
  }
}
```

```css
.textbox{
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div
  class="textbox prev textbox-1"
  id="textboxjs1"
  data-timerfunction="decrease">&lt; Prev</div>

<div class="textbox target textbox-2" id="textboxjs2">1</div>
<div class="textbox target textbox-3" id="textboxjs3">2</div>
<div class="textbox target textbox-4" id="textboxjs4">3</div>
<div class="textbox target textbox-5" id="textboxjs5">4</div>
<div class="textbox target textbox-6" id="textboxjs6">5</div>

<div class="textbox next textbox-7" id="textboxjs7">
Next &gt;
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. this is amazing, however, can i make them increase ( all of them ) while I hover on the last button ( Next > ) ?

Comment: I added the logic to deal with the `.next` button that will target all `.target` divs instead of `this`. This was better factored if the condition wasn't inside the handler itself. But it's just a small detail that only deserved to be said.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more solid and included also the decrementing feature on the prev button. I think I covered the whole story there and I hope it correctly addressed what you were expecting

Comment: Sorry, I tried to target those buttons but I couldn't make it work..thank you for your time, it was very helpful and i understand this better, but I also think it's too complex for my level right now to be playing with it

Comment: I don’t know what to say. The demo works correctly. Good luck